# toilet invigilator or toilet keeper

Tags: word-request, british-english

In our country, during an exam hour there is an invigilator whose duty is to stand guard outside the toilet. He makes the invigilation of cheating and records the list of students who use toilet during the exam time.

How should we call this teacher, toilet invigilator or toilet keeper?

Comment: Not really an answer, but in the Southeast US, I have never heard the word "invigilator" or "invigilation". Dictionaries tell me this word _is_ used in UK English. I guess it depends on your audience, but I would personally use "keeper", "minder", "watcher" or possibly even "proctor" rather than "invigilator".

Comment: My country is Myanmar. The exam system is roughly similar to India's. The question is related with the link http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23796/how-should-bathroom-breaks-be-handled-during-written-exams-to-avoid-cheating

Comment: Your country is Myanmar, but what group of English speakers are you writing this in English for? Americans? Brits? Australians?

Comment: For the British .

Comment: "Bathroom monitor" would be the equivalent English term in the US.

Comment: I agree with fixer1234's answer. But please note that a bathroom monitor may also just be someone who monitors behavior in the bathroom. But spoken in context, I'm sure everyone will understand anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call him an exam invigilator only! That's because he is there to keep a watch on whether a student has any access to study material and **not** toilet!

I found [a page *(opens a pdf document)*](https://www.eteach.com/DataFiles/VacDocs/9751/511643/Exam%20Invigilator%20Job%20Description.pdf) that mentions the job description of an exam invigilator. One of the points mentions:

> *Escorting candidates on toilet breaks ensuring no unauthorised material is consulted and that examination regulations are observed at all times*

However, there could be many [*types* of exam invigilators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exam_invigilator) namely chief and deputy chief depending on how schools categories in different countries. I can say that in India, it's just 'exam invigilators' and not a special one for 'toilet/washroom'.